# JavaScript - enumerating a nested object structure

Tags: javascript

I need help with parsing this object:

```
var user = {
    "10000068485": {"id":"10000068485","name":"Jenan"},
    "10000099257": {"id":"10000099257","name":"John"}
}
```

I need to read the `id` and `name` properties of each row:

```
1 row - id = 10000068485 and name = Jenan
2 row - id = 10000099257 and name = John
```

I've tried this so far:

```
for (var key in user) {
   if (user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     var obj = user[key];
     for (var prop in obj) {
       if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          //This read 4 rows and no 2 rows
       }
     }
   }
}
```

---

*comment: "I want to show id and name in one line."*

*comment: "In an html table."*

*comment: "I want to put the id and the name into two columns."*

Comment: What is your problem, exactly?

Comment: Your code is working correctly. Whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Who are you talking to? There's nothing wrong with asking for clarification.

Comment: @Marcin I want to show id and name in one line.

Comment: @Jenan: What is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: @Marcin I do not know how. That's why I asked.

Comment: @Jenan: How do you define a "line". Are you outputting to the console? Or are you building a string? Or are the values being placed in an HTML table?

Comment: @Jenan: Alright. Well there's the trouble then. The only part of the code that you provided in the question is the generic part that appears to work properly. Since the part you're having trouble with is the table insertion, then that would arguably be the most important part to include. Without knowing anything about your table structure, it's very difficult to answer.

Comment: @amnotiam Sorry for my question. I speak bad English. I wrote it wrong. :( I want to put the id and the name into two columns.

Comment: @Jenan: That's alright. I [added an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8870942/1106925) that hopefully will help. I still don't know anything about your table structure, so I just made one up. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @amnotiam: I was making an ironic comment to the OP, that played on Marcin's perfect request for much-needed clarification. It's (a) a shame that you didn't pick up on that, and (b) a shame that some moderator removed it, so that we can't talk about it any more. Getting sick of this site.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That was meant to be ironic? Uh, alright. Sorry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HTML table is this...

```
<table id=data_table>
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You could insert like this...

```
var user = {
    "10000068485": {"id":"10000068485","name":"Jenan"},
    "10000099257": {"id":"10000099257","name":"John"}
};

var tbody = document.getElementById('data_table').tBodies[0];

for (var key in user) {
   if (user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     var row = tbody.insertRow( tbody.rows.length );
     row.insertCell( 0 )
         .appendChild( document.createTextNode( user[key].id ) );
     row.insertCell( 1 )
         .appendChild( document.createTextNode( user[key].name ) );
   }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qtcTS/1/

---

Here's an example that creates new elements in a div.

The resulting structure will look like:

```
<div id=main>
    <p>
        <span>10000068485</span> <span>Jenan</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>10000099257</span> <span>John</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

JS

```
var user = {
    "10000068485": {"id":"10000068485","name":"Jenan"},
    "10000099257": {"id":"10000099257","name":"John"}
};

var p, main = document.getElementById('main');

for (var key in user) {
   if (user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     p = main.appendChild( document.createElement('p') );
     p.appendChild( document.createElement('span') )
                .appendChild( document.createTextNode( user[key].id ) );

     p.appendChild( document.createElement('span') )
                .appendChild( document.createTextNode( user[key].name ) );
   }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qtcTS/2/

Comment: Can you help me? I would do the same logic to html div.

Comment: @Jenan: Sure, I'll update with a solution. You'll need to modify it if you want different types of elements. I'll update in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 keys (the ids) with each of them having two keys (`id`, `name`). So in you very inner loop, it's 4 (= 2 x 2).

```
> for(key in user) {
...   obj = user[key];
...   for (prop in obj) {
...      console.log(obj[prop])
...   }
... }
10000068485
Jenan
10000099257
John
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this

```
for (var key in user) {
     var obj = user[key];
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty("name") && obj.hasOwnProperty("id")) {
        alert("id:"+obj.id +" & name:"+obj.name);
   }
}
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TQEND/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in user) {
    if (user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var obj = user[key];
        var row = { };
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                row[prop] = obj[prop];
            }
        }
        // at this stage the row variable will contain the id and name properties
        // row = { id: '10000068485', name: 'Jenan' }
        console.log(row);
    }
}
```